# Adding same data value into two separate tables using SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis

I am working on copying a table by pulling data from a Table1 in db1 into Table2 in db2.

Table2 will contain an extra column for TimeID which is dynamically generated when data is pulled into Table2. So every fetched record at a particular time will have the same TimeID in Table2. Also this TimeID has to be entered into a separate table say Table3 where it will be primary key.

I need to create a NEWID() and update it in two separate tables. How do I do that on SSIS?

Answer (score 0):

Can it just be done in a stored proc or SQL statement?

```
declare @guid uniqueidentifier, @processed datetime
select @guid = NEWID(), @processed = GETDATE()

insert into db2..table2 
select *, @processed as ProcessedDate
from db1..table1

insert into db2..table3
select @guid, @processed
```

Comment: There might be a tiiiny gap between setting the date variable and extracting the data from table1. If that's an issue, then don't set the variable BEFORE extracting; rather use this insert-select line: "select *, GETDATE()", and then set the processed variable AFTERWARDS (before your table3 insert) using: SELECT @processed = MAX(ProcessedDate) FROM db2..table2 (or, just do the insert into table3 using: select @ guid, max(ProcessedDate) from table2).

Comment: Thanks SeanW, but I don't want to hardcode intructions in database stored procedures. I want to develop a SSIS package programmatically later on based on Integration Services project that I am developing right now. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Just use an "Execute SQL Task" and put that SQL into the SQLStatement, if you don't want it in the DB's stored procs?